# Flask - (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed even after migration

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have created a one-to-many database relationship between the following:

models.py

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    histories = db.relationship('History', backref='admin', lazy=True)

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.id}', '{self.username}', '{self.email})"


class History(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "history"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    offender_ip = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    offender_mac = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    action = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    classification = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    case_id = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.id}', {self.date_posted}', '{self.offender_ip}', '{self.offender_mac}', '{self.action}'," \
            f" '{self.classification}', '{self.case_id}')"
```

I get the error when creating an instance of 'History' here:

```
@app.route("/block/add/result", methods=['GET', "POST"])
def block_submit_add():
    print(current_user)
    get_user = "user"
    get_password = "password"

    get_mac = request.form["mac"]
    get_offender_ip = request.form["off_ip"]
    get_classification = request.form["classification"]
    get_case_id = request.form["case_id"]
    now = datetime.now()

    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        history = History(date_posted=now, offender_ip=get_offender_ip,
                          offender_mac=get_mac, action="BLOCKED", classification=get_classification, case_id=get_case_id)
        db.session.add(history)
        db.session.commit()

        user = History.query.filter_by(offender_mac=get_mac).first()

        print(user.offender_ip)
        print(user.classification)
        print(user.get_case_id)
```

I also have a 'load_user' function that uses 'user_loader' from Flask-Login:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

Here is the full error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: history.user_id
[SQL: INSERT INTO history (date_posted, offender_ip, offender_mac, action, classification, case_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('2019-08-01 23:35:01.351985', '10.0.0.0', '00:00:00:00:00:00', 'BLOCKED', 'Test', '123', None)]
```

Is there a reason why 'History.user_id' is None? I have also tried to do a database migration/upgrade with Alembic and still receive the error.

Comment: When you "run database migrations", Alembic should create a migrations file for you. It's essential that you check those to make sure that what is actually executed is also how you envisioned it. It seems like you're not sure whether `user_id` should be nullable or not, but since you say `nullable=False`, you tell Alembic to enforce that the value can't be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set `user_id` when you create the new History object:

```
history = History(date_posted=now, offender_ip=get_offender_ip,
                  offender_mac=get_mac, action="BLOCKED", classification=get_classification, case_id=get_case_id)
```

It seems like `offender_mac` is what you use to identify a user by, if that is true I don't get why you also need a `user_id`.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!